# Branching points detection in processed image

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, image-processing

I want to get the branching coordinates from a computer-generated image like this one:

[image: Generated tree]

After `SkeletonTransform` and `Pruning`, I get:

[image: Skeletonized]

I would like to develop an algorithm that automatically detect and give coordinates of branching points (I could do it manually but really time consuming).

Thanks!

Edit: I already tried `MorphologicalBranchPoints` with poor results...

Comment: "I already tried MorphologicalBranchPoints with poor results..." Can you be specific about what you got and what you want instead?

Comment: @ Szabolcs It was more about a careful selection of thinning and skeletonize options. The result with `MorphologicalBranchPoints` wasn't good then.

Comment: Added another update.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`MorphologicalBranchPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MorphologicalBranchPoints.html).

```
im = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0AMj.png"]

skel = Pruning[Thinning[im], 20];

HighlightImage[skel, MorphologicalBranchPoints[skel]]
```

[image]

Another possibility is to use

```
skel1 = Pruning[Thinning[im, Method -> "MedialAxis"], 10];
```

as a start then smoothen the result using

```
skel2 = Thinning@Dilation[skel1, 5]
```

so that `MorphologicalBranchPoints` would not give false results.

```
HighlightImage[skel2, MorphologicalBranchPoints[skel2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

I notice there's a faint pink background that seems like a natural boundary. I've highlighted it to showcase this:

[image]

We can extract this curve and use it as the original boundary:

```
im = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ck2S.png"];
mask = FillingTransform[Thinning[Binarize[ColorReplace[im, White -> Black, .055], 0]], CornerNeighbors -> True]
```

[image]

And the simply call `MorphologicalBranchPoints`:

```
skel = Thinning[mask];
HighlightImage[skel, MorphologicalBranchPoints[skel], 1]
```

[image]

Comment: This is really clean!

Comment: by the way I think it's `Thinning[mask]` in this case, isn't it?

Comment: @Valacar Yes. I made the correction, thank you.